# Ubuntu 14.04 system hangs after installing pam module for ldap client with intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0

Tags: 14.04, ldap, vmware-workstation

I am running VMWare Workstation 10.0.2 on a Windows 8.1 host. I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 as a virtual machine. Everything works fine. All updates, upgrades and dist-upgrades are installed. After that I followed [this procedure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) to connect to my ldap server.

After rebooting the system it hangs with the following error in the terminal screen:

```
intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
```

I've seen the error before on this forum, however there it was non intrusive and could be mitigated by adding `paevm = "TRUE"` to the vmx config of the virtual machine. I tried that, but without any results. See [this fix](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1539).

How can I get the pam ldap client working on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: same for me; were you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Yeah I did. I thought that it continued to boot after a long time. You should look for a config file in `/etc/modprobe.d`. In that file you need to add `blacklist paevm`. I don't have the config anymore, so I cannot verify.

Comment: I see, I will look for it. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Please add the answer and/or close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system is not hanging. Just wait for a few minutes and the boot will continue. When booted into the system, edit your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `blacklist paevm` to the bottom of the file.

Comment: Yesterday I had to wait for at least 20 minutes with this intel_rapl error on the display, just after 'powering on' my VM.    (Though my circumstances were different.  It was a new VM, with Ubuntu 16.04 just installed, doing it's first reboot.)  The error was in orange text on a black screen.  Obviously 20 minutes is unacceptable.  But in my case it only happened once.  I have tried to reproduce it since then, and failed.  So I would reiterate the advice to wait (the first time it happens anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed by adding these three lines to the end of the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file:

- blacklist intel_rapl
- blacklist the_module name
- blacklist i2c_piix4